# Pull names from column in sheet 1 and place in column on another sheet removing duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for help with a formula if possible.

I have a sheet within a workbook called 'RAW' and in column 'I' it has a series of agent names. What i want to do is copy these names into the sheet named 'YTD' into column B but in the process of this also remove any duplicates that appear in the new unique list.

The formula i was working with is below however i when i try to amend it to what i need i get circular reference errors. Any help appreciated.

```
=INDEX(Raw!$I3:$I10000,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(Raw!I:I,Raw!i:Raw!i),0,0),0))
```

Comment: you can use advanced filter option if using formula is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this, I recommend you use the available manual tools already present in excel. Simply copy and paste the column as you would, and then in your new list, go to the Data Ribbon > Remove Duplicates.

Automation should be used when you have consistently repeating tasks with exactly the same form of input and output. For all of the random things you need to do in excel, relying on automation developed elsewhere can greatly reduce your actual speed at performing these tasks.

Comment: I wanted automation as the RAW sheet changes week on week and therefore the names also. By automating it would save me the task of copy and paste over and over again. I one of these people that like to automate averything where possible as workload is quite high and any saving on time is a great help